# + in ajax query string

Tags: jquery, ajax, urlencode

if i have + symbol in comment variable record is not submitted. is there any way i can encode the query string in jquery? i tried some of the methods but they didn't worked

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: rootURL + 'services/service.php?method=insertcomment',
     data: 'comment=' + comment+'&storyid='+storyid,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {
           if(data.code == 200)
                 $('#success-message')..show();
           else
                alert('failure');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode your data as URL.

Check the related post : [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

Or pass your data as JSON object :

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: rootURL + 'services/service.php?method=insertcomment',
     data: {comment : comment, storyid : storyid},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {
           if(data.code == 200)
                 $('#success-message').show();
           else
                alert('failure');
     }
});
```

Comment: I agree, data should be passed as an object.